# Find the definition and notations like ++ in Coq

Tags: coq

How can we get the definition/type for those notations like `"+"`, or `"++"` of `List`?

I have tried : `Search ++`, `Search "++"`, `Search (++)`,
 `SearchAbout ...` and
`Check ++`, `Check "++"`, `Check(++)`.

None of them work however...

`SearchAbout "++"` does show some info, but not the definition of `"++"`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Do:

```
Locate "++".
```

To lookup for notations.

Then you can `Print`/`Check` the actual term being denoted.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. But I'm still wondering is there a convenient command to do this in emacs & proof general ?

Comment: @luochen1990 In ProofGeneral, the default shortcuts are `C-c C-a C-c` for Check, and `C-c C-a C-p` for Print. If you use menus, they are somewhere in the ProofGeneral menus too.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a shortcut for "Locate" ?

Comment: Shortcut for Locate is `C-c C-a C-n`

Answer (score 8):

In addition to previous answer, you can use `Unfold "++"` to unfold it's definition without locating it first.

Example:

```
Coq < Goal forall A (l : list A), l ++ [] = [].
1 subgoal

  ============================
   forall (A : Type) (l : list A), l ++ [] = []

Unnamed_thm < unfold "++".
1 subgoal

  ============================
   forall (A : Type) (l : list A),
   (fix app (l0 m : list A) {struct l0} : list A :=
      match l0 with
      | [] => m
      | a :: l1 => a :: app l1 m
      end) l [] = []
```

Comment: Nit: presumably you meant `l ++ [] = l`, not `l ++ [] = []`?

Comment: @MarkDickinson that would make it provable, yes. :)