# Unfold a notation within a scope

Tags: coq

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26032966/3335288) provides a simple useful trick: `unfold ">="` is the same as `unfold ge` but does not require you to know that `>=` is the notation for `ge`.

Can you do the same for notations within a scope?

```
Require Import NArith.
Goal forall x, (x >= x)%N.
unfold ">=".
```

Here `unfold ">="` does not do anything because it tries to unfold `ge`, not `N.ge`.

I have found the following solution:

```
Open Scope N.
unfold ">=".
```

But is there a syntax allowing to unfold this notation without first opening the scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the template `unfold string % scope` as follows:

```
Require Import NArith.
Goal forall x, (x >= x)%N.
  unfold ">=" % N.
```

This gives us the goal `forall x : N, (x ?= x)%N <> Lt` with unfolded `>=`.

Comment: `(term) % scope` is the standard syntax for local opening of an interpretation scope. It so happens that Coq accepts it in this case too. It's actually not `scope`, but `key`, I'm being sloppy here.